# Goroutines not working when method on a struct is called

Tags: go

I'm trying to get into go and I'm facing a problem which appears when using go routines on a method of a struct. What I was expecting is that the code prints the following output:

> Item 1 was asked if it's alive
>
> Item 2 was asked if it's alive

But it's not printing anything. When I leave out the "go"routines (at struct1.isAlive()) it's working fine. How can I make the goroutines work?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type somestruct struct {
    ID              int
    ItemName        string
}

func (s *somestruct) isAlive() (alive bool) {
    alive = true
    fmt.Printf("%s was asked if it's alive \n", s.ItemName)
    return
}


func main() {
    struct1 := somestruct{
        ID:1,
        ItemName:"Item 1"}

    struct2 := somestruct{
        ID:2,
        ItemName:"Item 2"}


    go struct1.isAlive()
    go struct2.isAlive()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue is that the program exits before the functions could execute and print out to stdout.
One simple fix is to wait for both of the go routines to finish and then exit from main function. 
Here is a link that you can refer : https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/02/15/how-to-wait-for-all-goroutines-to-finish-executing-before-continuing/

here is your program implemented with WaitGroups

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type somestruct struct {
    ID       int
    ItemName string
    wg       *sync.WaitGroup
}

func (s *somestruct) isAlive() (alive bool) {
    defer s.wg.Done()
    alive = true
    fmt.Printf("%s was asked if it's alive \n", s.ItemName)
    return
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    struct1 := somestruct{
        ID:       1,
        ItemName: "Item 1",
        wg:       &wg,
    }

    struct2 := somestruct{
        ID:       2,
        ItemName: "Item 2",
        wg:       &wg,
    }

    go struct1.isAlive()
    go struct2.isAlive()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Doesn't waiting for the concurrent routine to finish obviate the purpose of having them? In my case I want to goroutine to execute a long running process while my API function returns.

Comment: Yes, if you are waiting for each co routine to finish when not executing any other routines. but here we have 2 co routines running at the same time. and we wait for both of them to finish.

In your case, I assume you could do the same or create a co-routine for long running process and have API function run on the main thread and wait for the long running co-routine to finish.